# How can i prevent from navbar from overlapping title?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently having some issues with my navbar.  Right now it looks like image one but I want to make it look like image 2. How would I do that? Is it something on CSS that I have to add?

```css
/* Nav Bar*/
.navbar-brand{
    height: 3.5rem;
}

.navbar-nav li {
    padding-right: 0.1rem;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-item:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF7200;
}

.nav
{
    
}
```

```html
<body>
  <!--Navigation-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="../img/IMG_0537.PNG" alt="KAJ Construction Logo"/>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-Services" >Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-Gallery" >Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-Contact" >Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

[How it currently looks when services link is clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7h8A.png)
[How I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUxNd.png)

Comment: Check [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/#placement): _Fixed navbars use position: fixed, meaning they’re pulled from the normal flow of the DOM and may require custom CSS (e.g., padding-top on the <body>) to prevent overlap with other elements._

Comment: If you don't want fixed nav bar remove "fixed-top" class, this will fix your problem.

Comment: I want the navbar to be fixed

Answer (score 0):

Add some built-in bootstrap margin and padding like mt-3 (mt means margin-top ) use p-2 (padding from every side) 2 and 3 defines 2rem or 3rem use this it will fix

Comment: Would i add this in my css file?

Comment: You wouldn't add it to the css file, you'd add it to your body element so the top is padded thus not overlapping

Comment: use it in as class name, these are the class names of bootstrap use it in your services section class names

Answer (score 0):

Since your header is `position: fixed`, you need to give the content of your page a margin-top equal to its height:

```css
/* Nav Bar*/
.navbar-brand{
    height: 3.5rem;
}

.navbar-nav li {
    padding-right: 0.1rem;
}

.nav-link {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}

.nav-item:hover {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #FF7200;
}

main{
    margin-top: 72px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <!--Navigation-->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <img class="navbar-brand" src="http://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="KAJ Construction Logo"/>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-Services" >Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-Gallery" >Gallery</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#section-Contact" >Contact Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <main>
  <h1>Our Services</h1>
  </main>
```